# Linq over InputStream from HttpPostedFileWrapper

Tags: c#, linq, httppostedfilebase

Is it possible to apply a Linq query from a HttpPostedFileWrapper?

My web app allows users to select a bunch of .csv files.  I now need to open those files and import them.

My previous code, which uses paths and file names looks like;

```
            importedList = (from csvLine in File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                            let x = csvLine.Split(',')
                            select new ImportedXDock
                            {
                                StoreNumber = int.Parse(x[0]),
                                DCNumber = int.Parse(x[1]),
                                DeliveryDay = x[2],
                                Activity = x[3],
                                ActivityDay = x[4],
                                Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x[5])

                            }).ToList();
```

However, now that i have a collection of `HttpPostedFileWrapper` objects how would I do the same?

**edit**

Or do I need to convert it to something and then read the file?

Comment: Could you loop over the HttpPostedFileWrapper file names instead `wrapper.Select(w => w.FileName)`

Comment: @steaks, write that up as the answer.  Can't believe I didn't actually try that.  Proof that when you look at an issue long enough you get tunnel vision!  Thanks

Comment: Glad to help!  I've can certainly relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to loop over the file names instead of the input streams

```
foreach (var fileName in wrapper.Select(w => w.FileName))
{
    yield return (from csvLine in File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                    let x = csvLine.Split(',')
                    select new ImportedXDock
                    {
                        StoreNumber = int.Parse(x[0]),
                        DCNumber = int.Parse(x[1]),
                        DeliveryDay = x[2],
                        Activity = x[3],
                        ActivityDay = x[4],
                        Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x[5])

                    }).ToList();
}
```